# How to get wordpress client id and client secret for iOS Application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, wordpress

I am checking open source wordpress application for iOS (https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPress-iOS) to run that I need following client id and client secret

```
#define WPCOM_API_CLIENT_ID @""
#define WPCOM_API_CLIENT_SECRET @""
```

I have searched everywhere but did not get any clue about it :/

Help me if you have any idea. Thanks.

Comment: Link to open source wordpress application??

Comment: @Mundi https://github.com/wordpress-mobile/WordPress-iOS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to request your own client ID and secret key.

You can do this at the [WordPress.com website](https://developer.wordpress.com/apps/) (the instructions for which [I found here](http://developer.wordpress.com/docs/wpcc/).

And once you get them, you can use them in [OAuth2 authentication](http://developer.wordpress.com/docs/oauth2/)

Comment: Thanks for reply, Let me check :)

Comment: I've modified my answer a bit (it has nothing to do with Google & GDrive, which is what I was originally guessing).

Comment: It gives me error like Error Domain=WordPressComOAuthError Code=2 "Client cannot use "password" grant_type" UserInfo=0xd31dd60 {NSLocalizedDescription=Client cannot use "password" grant_type}

Comment: what gives you that error?  Also, did you actually find and create your new client ID & client secret?

Comment: I got client id and client secret by making an app at https://developer.wordpress.com/apps but when I try login it gives the error I mentioned

Comment: well that sounds like a different (and new) question than the one you asked here... you've solved the problem of getting a client ID and client secret, so maybe you should create a new question?

Comment: @UndercoverDeveloper : I am also getting same error : Error Domain=WordPressComOAuthError Code=2 "Client cannot use "password" grant_type" UserInfo=0xd31dd60 {NSLocalizedDescription=Client cannot use "password" grant_type}  Can you guide me to solve it ? I have created APP on wordpress and using its Client id and secret key.